# why I can't return anonymous type as generic in C#, while I can do the same for method parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, return-type, anonymous-types, method-parameters

Consider this code:

```
using System;

class EntryPoint{

    static void Main(){
        f(new{ Name = "amir", Age = 24 });
    }

    static void f <T> (T arg){}

}
```

This code compiles with C# 9 compiler. I can send anonymous type where a generic type is expected. My question is why I can't do the same for method return types?

For example, consider this code:

```
using System;

class EntryPoint{

    static void Main(){
        object obj = f();
    }

    static T f <T> (){
        return new{ Name = "amir", Age = 24 };
    }

}
```

It will get the following compile errors:

main.cs(6,22): error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'EntryPoint.f()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

main.cs(10,16): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type '<anonymous type: string Name, int Age>' to 'T'

Why these same errors do not appear in the other code. In the other code the anonymous type is also implicitly converted to T. Why this can't happen here?

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: Why do you think the return version is a generic?  It always returns the same type, there is nothing generic about it.

Comment: I know that the method always return the same type. What I ask is why the same technique that was applied to method parameters, do not apply to method return types?

Comment: The type system just doesn't work that way. Giving `f` a type parameter means the *caller* gets to inject the type (either explicitly or inferred), which is what happens in your first example, but in your second example it would never be legal to call `f` with any type other than the type declared in `f` itself, and there is no way to infer `T` at the caller site. You can return `object`, but you cannot make `f` return an anonymous type and still have it be strongly typed, since you can't name the type. This is not specific to anonymous types; `T f<T>() => 1;` isn't legal either.

Comment: @AmirValizadeh: You seem to be treating a generic type parameter as an automatically-inferred type.  That is not what a generic type parameter IS, that is a feature of generic type parameters, but a generic type parameter IS a parameter of a family of classes or methods.  You have no family of methods here.  For type inference independent of generic parameterization, there is the `var` keyword (but it also is not allowed on function return types).

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous types are just types that the C# compiler defines for you. So lets change your example to use concrete types;

```cs
public class Foo {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

static void Main(){
    f1(new Foo{ Name = "amir", Age = 24 });
}

static void f1<T> (T arg){}

static T f2<T> (){
    return new Foo{ Name = "amir", Age = 24 };
}
```

Now it should be obvious in the second example, that types `T` and `Foo` are not the same.